# Query regarding example question 28 in N1 Shin Kanzen Master Dokkai

Tags: jlpt

The question explains that Lana is bringing friends that cannot eat pork or beef, and to circle which restaurants would be appropriate based on that. Restaurant 4 clearly states that there is both beef and vegetables available, so I allowed it as a candidate. But when I looked at the answer it was not included. If there is a vegetable option, how come this is not included as part of the answer?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Because they are specialised in [しゃぶしゃぶ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%97%E3%82%83%E3%81%B6%E3%81%97%E3%82%83%E3%81%B6). They do serve vegetables, so technically someone who doesn't eat beef could survive in the restaurant, but the whole restaurant is focused on beef.  Imagine a steakhouse, whose salad is also tasty. You'd not want to bring a friend who doesn't eat beef there.

---

I'll add some more information after getting some upvotes:

- In order to solve this question, what you'll have to read is the third column (特徴), which states beef and vegetable is featured in the restaurant.  It's a question aimed at determining your language level, so don't think too much about the detail. Beef is one of the main component of the restaurant, therefore it's out.  Restaurant 2 and 3 *might* serve beef too? The friend avoid beef and pork perhaps because of a very sensitive allergy, so you'll have to be careful about the structure of the kitchen? Don't worry about that.
- I cannot say your reasoning is entirely flawed. If I were you and if this were an exam in class, I'd talk to the teacher and see if my answer could also be accepted. This is not, so consider that you took an approach that wasn't expected by the creator of the question, and that the question wasn't created with the deepest care, and learn that this is probably the level of detail in the exam. And move on, it's a tiny disagreement.

In a totally different layer, in real life, don't bring anyone who don't eat beef to a beef-しゃぶしゃぶ restaurant. Vegetables served in しゃぶしゃぶ restaurants are basically for garnish: you'll enjoy them, I'll have large amount and be happy because I love vegetables. But not without beef.